# Consulta or filterscope eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Necesito reformular esta consulta:

```
select * from `productos` 
inner join `equivalencias` on `equivalencias`.`codigo` = `productos`.`codigo` 

where (`equivalencias`.`equivalencia` like ?)  and (`productos`.`codigo` like ?) 

and `activo` = ? 
order by `productos`.`codigo` asc
```

pero donde dice:

```
where (`equivalencias`.`equivalencia` like ?)  and (`productos`.`codigo` like ?)
```

necesito que sea:

```
where (`equivalencias`.`equivalencia` like ?) OR (`productos`.`codigo` like ?)
```

La consulta la obtengo a través de:

```
Producto::join('equivalencias','equivalencias.codigo','=','productos.codigo')
            ->filterEquivalencia($codigo)
            ->filterCodigoEquiv($codigo)

...

 public function scopeFilterCodigoEquiv($query, $codigo)
    {
        if (trim($codigo) != '') {
            $query->orWhere('productos.codigo', 'like', '%' . str_replace('/', '', $codigo) . '%');
        }
    }
    public function scopeFilterEquivalencia($query, $codigo)
    {
        if (trim($codigo) != '') {
            $query->orWhere('equivalencias.equivalencia', 'like', '%' . str_replace('/', '', $codigo) . '%');

        }
    }
```

Pero aunque en los scopes la cláusula es `orWhere()`, en la consulta resultante sigue apareciendo `AND`.

Como lo podría resolver?

EDIT:

Ya lo resolvi, de la siguiente manera: utilizando un solo scopeFilter, al llamar a cada scope se van anidando en AND's, lo que hice fue eliminar un scope y dentro del otro agregar la parte de consulta que anteriormente estaba dentro del scope borrado y utilizando orWhere.

```
public function scopeFilterCodigoEquiv($query, $codigo)
{
    if (trim($codigo) != '') {
        $query->where('productos.codigo', 'like', '%' . str_replace('/', '', $codigo) . '%')
        ->orWhere('equivalencias.equivalencia', 'like', '%' . str_replace('/', '', $codigo) . '%');
    }
}
```

Comment: No termino de entender cual es la duda, considera explicarte un poco mejor por favor

Comment: necesito pasar de AND a OR en la consulta, y a $query-> orWhere, where le da lo mismo.... no logro cambiar la consulta

Comment: Agrega la solución en una respuesta en vez de en la pregunta, así podrás marcarla como aceptada

Answer (score 1):

Para poder traducir las `consultas SQL` a eloquent sin alejarte de la `sintaxis` seria habilitando `SQL` en `Laravel` y te quedaria así:

```
use DB;
```

```
$consulta = DB::select(`
    select * from 'productos' 
    inner join 'equivalencias' on 'equivalencias'.'codigo' = 'productos'.'codigo' 
    where ('equivalencias'.'equivalencia' like ?) 
    and ('productos'.'codigo' like ?) and 'activo' = ? 
    order by 'productos'.'codigo' asc
`)->get();
```

Lo cual no se ve muy nuevo que digamos, entonces seria mejor hacer tal consulta al estilo `Query Builer`

```
    public function rvtienda($codpro, $equivale, $activo)   {
        // puedes usar '%'.$equivale.'%'
        $reporte = DB::table("productos as pro")
        ->join('equivalencias as equi', 'equi.codigo', '=', 'pro.codigo')
        ->select(
            'pro.codigo as codigo',
            //agregas mas datos que quieres mostrar
        )
        ->where("equi.equivalencia","like",$equivale)
        ->where("pro.codigo","like",$codpro)
        ->where("pro.activo",$activo)
        ->orderBy("codigo")
        ->get();
        return $reporte;
    }
```

Comment: Tu primer opción de consulta no es Eloquent

Comment: Me gusta la respuesta, "Siempre que puedas evita eloquent", Se ha demostrado que un consulta eloquent es mucho mas lenta que un DataBase QueryBuilder y este a su vez es mas lento que un simple query. No utilizar un ORM, no te hace mal programador, es más aprender mas sobre SQL siempre es bueno.